# Sending json string to C# web service from android

Tags: c#, android, json, service, web

I am triying to comunicate my android application with a json c# web service
I got to retrieve a json object from the web service but I am failing sending a json object to the web service.

Here is my web service code

```
 [WebMethod]
    public void recibePosicion(string json_cad)
    {

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Posicion nueva_posicion = jss.Deserialize<Posicion>(json_cad); 
        PosicionDAO posicion_dao = new PosicionDAO();
        posicion_dao.InsertaPosicion(nueva_posicion);


    }
```

and here is my andorid code

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
         HttpResponse response;
         JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

         try
         {
             HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:1218/JSON.asmx/recibePosicion");
             post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
             post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


             json.put("idPosicion", "-1");
             json.put("x", "100");
             json.put("y", "200");
             StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);  
             se.setContentType("application/json");
             post.setEntity(se);                                  

            HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(post);

            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
               Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
               return null;
            }





         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println("Cannot Estabilish Connection");
         }
```

I get statuscode 500.
Instead if i change the web method to

public void recibePosicion()

I get to call the service but i don´t i don´t know how to get the json data.

Please i would apreciate any tip to resolve that issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What exception is thrown by the server?

Comment: 1. Add `static` to asp.net WebMethod `public static void recibePosicion(string json_cad)` 2. What string you get when you use `json.toString()` 3. Debug your program

Comment: did the issue solved?

Answer (score -1):

There are few mistakes in your code:

1. WebMethod must be `static`
2. You want to get json object in webmethod but your webmethod's
   parameter is of type `string`, change it to `object` instead:

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public static void recibePosicion(object json_cad){

       JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       Posicion nueva_posicion = jss.Deserialize<Posicion>(json_cad); 
       PosicionDAO posicion_dao = new PosicionDAO();
       posicion_dao.InsertaPosicion(nueva_posicion);

   }
   ```

Comment: Hi Coder,   I have tried making the method static and changing the parameter type to object but I keep receiving statusCode 500 on the client side the server does not get the call.

Comment: when i do the json.toString the cad I send looks as follows:

Comment: {"y":"200","idPosicion":"-1","x":"100"}

Comment: Try changing webmethod signature to `public static void recibePosicion(string y, string idPosicion, string x)` and set them directly to `Posicion`

Comment: Try changing order of parameters `public static void recibePosicion(string idPosicion, string x, string y)`, what is webmethod's code after editing ?

Comment: hi coder I tried both public static void recibePosicion(string y, string idPosicion, string x) and public static void recibePosicion(string idPosicion, string x, string y) and still not working